# Install IDF Espressif make menuconfig fatal error

Tags: makefile, arduino, raspberry-pi, esp32

I want to install the Espressif IDF on my Raspberry PI 3.

I've followed a tutorial to clone github files and so one...

I'm at the step where I have to "make menuconfig" but I get a fatal error.
The fatal error message is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ESP32/premier $ make menuconfig

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/ESP32/esp-idf/tools/kconfig'
cc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -DCURSES_LOC="<ncurses.h>" -DLOCALE -MD   -c -o mconf.o mconf.c
mconf.c:1047:1: fatal error: opening dependency file mconf.d: Permission denied
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mconf.o' failed
make[1]: *** [mconf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ESP32/esp-idf/tools/kconfig'
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/pi/ESP32/esp-idf/tools/kconfig/conf', needed by '/home/pi/ESP32/esp-idf/tools/kconfig/mconf'.  Stop.
```

Would someone has encountered this issue ???

Comment: Have you done any step from the tutorial with `sudo` that was not supposed to be ?

Comment: Yes it is true. I have followed the tutorial from the folder /opt/ESP32 and then I did use `sudo` . When I had this message, I moved all the folder to my workspace `/home/pi/`. Do you think it is the reason of the problem ? Should I start again without using `sudo` ?

Comment: That could be the source of your problem yes. You should give it a try

Comment: Thank you, i gonna try !

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was the problem, by using `sudo` command from outside of my workspace I got the error.

I have started again the tutorial in my workspace without using `sudo` and this time it works. Really great, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Permission based problems, either:
* As mentioned in the comments, restart tutorial by not deviating, or
* Fix permissions, in your "home"-case (otherwise /opt/...)

```
chmod -R 777 /home/pi/ESP32/esp-idf/
```